# princexml footer shows only first line

Tags: php, html, css, princexml

Hiho,
I have a problem with princexml.
I need to render pages with a repeating footer.
This onbe works fine, but on every site is only the first line from the footer content is shown.
The footer content is a table with two rows.
The first row has on every cell more than one line. 
The problem is that only the first line from the first row is shown and not the whole table.
Does anybody has an idea why?

The HTML-Part from the footer:

```
<table id="footer" style="height: 67px; width: 100%;" border="0" frame="void" rules="none">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>#BetreiberDaten</td>
<td style="width: 2%;">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 40%;">#GesellschafterBeschreibung</td>
<td style="width: 2%;">&nbsp;</td>
<td>#BankAdresse</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="5">#Rechnungsart_#Buchungscode_#Seitenzahl</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and the css part(s):

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 15pt;
    page-break-before: always;
    @bottom {
        content: flow(footer);
        margin: 0;
    }
}    
#footer
{
    width:100%;
    padding:2mm;
    text-align:left;
}

#footer td
{
    font-size:6pt;
}

div.pdf-footer-page-counter span.pdf-footer-page-counter-page {
    font-size: 6pt;
    content: counter(page);
}
div.pdf-footer-page-counter span.pdf-footer-page-counter-page-total {
    font-size: 6pt;
    content: counter(pages);
}

table#footer {flow: static(footer, start);}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code you are using?

Comment: I add the code to the question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Seems like its just a bug.